# Bootstrap horizontal scroll for div with min-width when inside col

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm looking to build a bootstrap v4 grid with 3 cols, but some of the content within the col needs to have a min-width. Therefore they should have a horizontal scroll (overflow-x) but there seems to be some overlap and the scrollbar and content are appearing outside the col.
Essentially the div of Col content 1 (orange border) should all fit within the Col container 1 (black border)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="border: solid 1px black" class="col-4">
        Col container 1
        <div style="min-width: 1000px; overflow-x: scroll;border: solid 1px orange">Col content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div style="border: solid 1px blue" class="col-4">
        Col container 2
      </div>
      <div style="border: solid 1px yellow" class="col-4">
        Col container 3
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were going for? The code is pretty much self-explanatory. I did place the new css in a class `.wrapScroll` as opposed to inline.

You mention the need for a `min-width` but I did not understand that need so did not use `min-width`.

```css
.wrapScroll {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="border: solid 1px black" class="col-4">
        Col container 1
        <div class="wrapScroll">Col content 1 - Let's make this a bit longer for demonstration purposes...</div>
      </div>
      <div style="border: solid 1px blue" class="col-4">
        Col container 2
      </div>
      <div style="border: solid 1px yellow" class="col-4">
        Col container 3
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks looks like this is what im looking for. Also works if i set width for a child div in the content div as well!